# Uniqueness of Rectifying Coordinates: Question for Arnold's ODE Book

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In section 7 of his book *Ordinary Differential Equations*, VI Arnold explains the `rectification theorem', that, given an ordinary differential equation

$$\dot{\mathbb{x}} = \mathbb{v(x)}$$
where $\mathbb{v}$ is smooth, and given a point $\mathbb{x_0}$ such that $\mathbb{v(x_0)}\neq 0$, then in some sufficiently small neighbourhood of $\mathbb{x_0}$ one can choose a coordinate system $(y_1,\ldots, y_n)$ such that, in this coordinate system, the equation is transformed into:

$$\dot{y}_1 = 1,\quad \dot{y}_2 =\cdots = \dot{y}_n=0$$

Then in problem 1 of section 7.2 he asks:

> Are the rectifying coordinates $y_i$ uniqely defined? Prove that in 1 dimension the coordinate $y$ is defined to within an affine transformation $\bar{y} = \alpha y + \beta$.

I can't see how this can possibly be true. Suppose that
$$\dot{x} = v(x)$$
and we've cleverly chosen the rectifying coordinates
$$y = f(x)$$
so that
$$\dot{y} = \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{df}{dx} \dot{x} = 1.$$

Then if we consider $\bar{y} = \alpha y + \beta = \alpha f(x) + \beta$, then
$$\dot{\bar{y}} = \frac{d\bar{y}}{dy}\frac{dy}{dt} = \alpha \dot{y} = \alpha \neq 1.$$
so $\bar{y}$ cannot be a rectifying coordinate.

Intuitively, I can see that rectifying coordinates remains such under translations (i.e. adding $\beta$), but multiplication by $\alpha$ scales the vector field, and I feel this should interfere with the $\dot{y}_1=1$ term, as the maths seems to show.

Taking it as axiomatic that Arnold isn't wrong - where is my 
misunderstanding? :)

Comment: On intuitive level (and in very simple case) it could be explained this way: if you apply a uniform expansion $aE$ then it stretches vector field by $a$ times, but if we expand this new vector field as a sum of vectors of *induced* basis (which is obtained from old basis by stretching all vectors $a$ times), then expansion is the same. And here I'm left puzzled too. It's only a guess, I'm trying to understand what's really happening here too.

Comment: @Evgeny Yes, that was my initial intuition also, that perhaps the basis vectors were stretched. But I can't get the maths to work that way :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm stuck here too, I need to do some revision of my knowledge :) at moments like this you kinda begin to understand why some people like coordinate free approachand struggle for it  :)